# sublime text 2 change indent template

Tags: indentation, sublimetext

I would like change the basic indentation on template ruby haml.
He is set when I create a new file to 'Tab Size: 4'
How change it in 'Spaces: 2'?

Thanks.

Comment: Flagged as a duplicate for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474090/how-do-i-force-sublime-text-2-to-use-two-spaces-per-tab) as the other more recent question was phrased a bit more clearly and had more votes/an easier solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Indenting code in Sublime text 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495007/indenting-code-in-sublime-text-2)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a better and easier way to set the indentation. To **change indentation for *all file types*** go to:

```
Preferences -> Settings - Default/User
```

To **change indentation for *a specific file type***, open a file type of your choice in the editor, and then go to:

```
Preferences -> Settings -> More -> Syntax Specific -> User
```

In both cases Sublime Text will open a file called `Ruby.sublime-settings`. Save the following settings:

```
{
  "tab_size": 2,
  "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
}
```

You can read more about this in this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474090/how-do-i-force-sublime-text-2-to-indent-two-spaces-per-tab?rq=1).

Answer (score 22):

To change the indentation settings just for ruby files create a new file named `Ruby.sublime-settings`, based on your OS, in 
`%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 2\Packages\User` or 
`~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 2/Packages/User/` or 
`~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/User/'`
with the following content:

```
{
  // The number of spaces a tab is considered equal to
  "tab_size": 2,

  // Set to true to insert spaces when tab is pressed
  "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
}
```

Comment: This should be reflected in the original Ruby Package.

Comment: While this answer works fine - thanks! - I just noticed a duplicate question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474090/how-do-i-force-sublime-text-2-to-use-two-spaces-per-tab) that has an easier way to create/edit the Ruby-specific settings file: ```Preferences -> Settings -> More -> Syntax Specific -> User```

Answer (score 5):

To change indentation within the document, go to `View > Indentation > Convert Tabs to Spaces`.  To make this change within the document for future edits, go to `View > Indentation > Spaces Width: 2`.  Additionally, if you have the status bar visible, you can you can click where it says `Tab Size: 4` and change the indentation here from the context menu.

Comment: My goal isn't just change to one file the indentation. But change the basic settings to all ruby files. Thanks.