# How do I force Sublime Text to indent two spaces per tab?

Tags: editor, sublimetext2, sublimetext, indentation

Is there a way to force Sublime Text 2 to always indent two spaces per tab when working with Ruby files?

I know that indentation can be set under the `view -> indentation` menu option, but it does not stick. Every time I open a new file and hit tab, it reverts back to four spaces.

Comment: Sublime is slightly different/weird by default.  Although it may save the file with multiple spaces the editor it self deletes both spaces if it identifies it as indentation.

Answer (score 981, accepted):

If you want it for *all* files, go to `Preferences -> Settings - Default/User`.   But as several comments below indicate, Syntax Specific settings can limit it to just the languages you choose.

To limit this configuration to Ruby files, first open up a Ruby file in the editor, and then go to `Preferences -> Settings - Syntax Specific`. This should open a settings window named `Ruby.sublime-settings`

Save these settings:

```
{
  "tab_size": 2,
  "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
  "detect_indentation": false
}
```

Repeat for any other syntax types by opening a file of that type and going back to the preferences to open the correct preferences file for that syntax.

*I have edited this to include the "detect_indentation" line per the requests in comments;   I previously used the Default/User to set my tab size, and have not needed the tab detection, but whether that is due to the global config or due to the fact that I have rarely opened files with tabs, I do not know.*

Restarting should not be necessary, although in some instances it can be.

Comment: From build 2181. You can configure the settings from Preferences -> Settings - Default/User. Best to put it in the User settings as that is the intended approach.

Comment: @KevinJalbert (and DGM)  Actually he should put that in syntax specific settings, so it only affects Ruby files.

Comment: Notice the value is **true** and *not* "true".

Comment: This is especially useful since Sublime Text's own website documentation incorrectly suggests using camelCase instead of underscores in the setting keys... still. (http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/indentation)

Comment: @EricGoldberg - I'm not sure how you got to that documentation page, but if you go to http://www.sublimetext.com > Support, and under Documentation, click the Sublime Text 2 link, you are brought to http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2 - from there, you can find the docs on indentation, and the setting keys correctly use underscore: http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/indentation.html

Comment: @jbyrd I probably did a Google search. They should update older docs pages and link to version 2 / 3 of the docs, or they'll be fighting their own Google rankings for quite a while after each new release.

Comment: I was looking for the exact opposite (4 spaces) for an existing file, this worked: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/can-i-easily-change-all-existing-2-space-indents-to-4-space-indents/40158/2

Answer (score 173):

If you want to force your chosen tab setting, ignoring what's likely already going on in the file, then you should include `detect_indentation` in your configuration (your User settings or your Syntax Specific settings, depending on if you want it global or per-filetype):

```
{
    "tab_size": 2,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
    "detect_indentation": false
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Without `detect_indentation` turned off I was getting very strange behavior (it was detecting the indentation incorrectly and using that instead of what I had specified in my settings).

Comment: Doing this in default settings worked for me. Make sure you look to see if the setting already exists. If you add it and it's declared later as true, it will remain set as true.

Comment: Be aware that changes to the Default Settings will be overwritten by Sublime Text updates, etc. Changes to the User Settings will not be overwritten.

Comment: THANK YOU!! `"detect_indentation":false` is *critical* else the other settings are ignored.   finally!

Comment: It is a good point but your example is inappropriately indented ;-)

Answer (score 107):

You can also do this with the text link in the bottom bar of Sublime Text 2 ( On the right side ) that says "Tab Size 4" by default, click that and a window comes up with options to set the tab size from 1 space all the way up to 8 spaces and includes options to convert tabs to spaces and spaces to tabs.

Looks like this:

[image: Tab Options in Sublime Text 2]

Comment: Great tip, but do you know if that becomes a sticky setting? For example, changing the indentation from the top menubar only applies to the current open file, and not others, which was my original problem.

Comment: This **does not work**. It's a good tip, but it's not sticky: closing and reopening the file (or opening another file) reverts indentation to four spaces.

Comment: Yeah, it is not sticky, it's per file. You have to go to into the settings of Sublime Text to setup your default setting for tabs/spaces.

Comment: This resolved my issue in Sublime Text 3. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, along the Status Bar, bottom right corner you will see Spaces: 2 or Spaces: 4, when you left click on this it brings up an option window to set the Indent style and Tab width.

Comment: This actually worked for me, but the reason, I think, is that this setting overrides the Preferences->Settings. When I opened a code block (curly) bracket and pressed Enter, Sublime didn't use preferences to determine the size of the indentation, but rather the setting in this menu. Only once I had *both* the preferences and this setting changed to my desired indentation size, then my new setting was remembered throughout all sessions and files.

Answer (score 37):

Can I suggest [EditorConfig](http://EditorConfig.org)? There is an [extension](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/EditorConfig) to autoload and apply the `.editorconfig` file. Then just create one in the root of your project.

`.editorconfig`

```
[*.rb]
indent_style = tab
indent_size = 2
```

This way, your settings are project-specific and file-specific if you use different styles for each project or language.

---

Here is what my own `.editorconfig` looks like.

```
# editorconfig.org
root = true

[*]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
end_of_line = lf
charset = utf-8
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = true
```

Comment: I didn't want to make this a global change. So this was the only solution that worked. I did some research into EditorConfig and it looks very nice for IDEs that support it.

Comment: It just so happened that I already had an .editorconfig in my project and did not even know it.  (angular-cli generates one)

Comment: How is this not the top answer!?
Exactly what I was looking for.
Thanks!

Comment: I like the .editorconfig solution. It is configurable for each file and each project. You can have a consistent coding style across an entire team.

Answer (score 10):

I use [Stupid Indent](https://github.com/tzvetkoff/sublime_stupid_indent) package.

`Install Package` -> `Stupid Indent`

`Preferences` -> `Package Settings` -> `Stupid Indent` -> `Setting-Users`

Copy settings (of `Ruby` part) into.

```
{
    "configuration":
    [
        {
            "patterns": ["*.rb"],
            "tab_size": 2,
            "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: yup this is what i need :D

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: **WARNING**. Stupid Indent [**default**](https://github.com/tzvetkoff/sublime_stupid_indent/blob/master/Stupid%20Indent.sublime-settings) and custom settings force overwrite [**Sublime Text**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9474136/5951529) and [**EditorConfig**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24619474/5951529) settings. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the previous answers, including adding the detect_indentation line, and my tabs were still five spaces. Then I realized that selecting `Preferences -> Settings -> More -> Syntax Specific -> User`from a ruby file was opening up `Ruby on Rails.sublime-settings` for me, not `Ruby.sublime-settings`.

I renamed my `Ruby on Rails.sublime-settings` file to `Ruby.sublime-settings`. Finally two-space tabs worked! I went ahead and put the same settings in `Ruby on Rails.sublime-settings` as well, just to be sure.