# Can I set tab with to 2 spaces in ruby and 4 spaces in javascript with sublime text

Tags: sublimetext

Pretty self explanatory, I just want to set up sublime to use 2 space indents for everything other than javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I force Sublime Text 2 to indent two spaces per tab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474090/how-do-i-force-sublime-text-2-to-indent-two-spaces-per-tab)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes.  You can create syntax specific settings files.  Make a file named `Javascript.sublime-settings` and save it in Packages/Javascript.

Then add:

```
{
  "tab_size": 4,
  "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
}
```

For more information, check out the this page from the docs: http://readthedocs.org/docs/sublime-text-unofficial-documentation/en/latest/customization/settings.html

Comment: I think it should be saved in Packages/User/ instead, at least according to this: http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/indentation.html

Comment: If you're reading this comment, scroll down a little bit to check out the simpler approach in the answer below. Same code, but you don't need to worry about opening, finding, saving preferences.

Comment: Both paths of `Packages/Javascript/` and `Packages/User/` with filename `Javascript.sublime-settings` are worked.

Comment: I tried this and found a filename of `JavaScript.sublime-settings` (capital 'S') was the trick to making it work for me in `Packages/User/`. A less error-prone solution is posed below by @Hubro.

Answer (score 48):

The accepted answer is unnecessarily complicated. Just open a Ruby file in Sublime Text 2, then:

[image: Preferences -> Settings - More -> Syntax Specific - User]

This will create a new file called *Ruby.sublime-settings* in the *Packages/User* directory and open it for you. If the file already exists it will just be opened for editing. Now you just need to type in your preferred settings and save.

Comment: This doesn't address the fact that I wanted to use 4 spaces for javascript and 2 for everything else

Comment: @GregGuida: Sure it does. Set 2 spaces globally, then set 4 spaces for JavaScript using the syntax specific settings.