# Syntax highlighting for .js.erb won't stay as JavaScript

Tags: ruby, sublimetext3, sublimetext, erb

I have installed SublimeERB and while it works well for `.html.erb` files, `.js.erb` uses HTML syntax highlighting.

If I set "Open all with current extension as..." to JavaScript, it works, but the highlighting goes away the next time I open any `.js.erb` file. How can I get it to stick?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474090/how-do-i-force-sublime-text-2-to-indent-two-spaces-per-tab

Comment: @Mohamad That opened up an empty `erb.sublime-settings` file for me. What would I place in there to get HTML syntax for `.html.erb` and JavaScript syntax for `.js.erb`?

Comment: @Jane the package mentioned in my answer to the duplicate question will do what you want. Make sure you read the documentation, as you can do some pretty complex things with the plugin.

Comment: @MattDMo That looks complicated. Good a reason as any to starting learning regex I suppose :)