# Sublime: spacing is set to 2 but hitting Tab key still inserts 4 spaces

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have my tab size setting set to 2:

```
"tab_size": 2,
```

and this works fine - when I open files they're formatted to 2 spaces for indents.

However, when I use the Tab key when coding I still get indented by 4 spaces.

Would anyone know how to fix?

My settings file is:

```
{
    "default_line_ending": "unix",
    "ensure_newline_at_eof_on_save": true,
    "font_size": 13,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ],
    "rulers":
    [
        80
    ],
    "show_line_endings": true,
    "tab_size": 2,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already solved. `You gotta add detect_indentation": false`

Please refer to the link: [How do I force Sublime Text to indent two spaces per tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474090/how-do-i-force-sublime-text-to-indent-two-spaces-per-tab)