# Indenting code in Sublime text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

In Visual Studio I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to indent everything so the code is structured nicely and readable. Is there a shortcut in Sublime 2 to do the same?

Comment: this is auto indenting not auto formatting

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I reformat HTML code using Sublime Text 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839753/how-do-i-reformat-html-code-using-sublime-text-2)

Answer (score 854, accepted):

You can find it in `Edit` → `Line` → `Reindent`, but it does not have a shortcut by default.
You can add a shortcut by going to the menu `Preferences` → `Keybindings` → `User`, then add there:

```json
{ "keys": ["f12"], "command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": false} }
```

(example of using the <kbd>F12</kbd> key for that functionality)

The config files use JSON-syntax, so these curly braces have to be placed comma-separated in the square-brackets that are there by default. If you don't have any other key-bindings already, then your whole `Keybindings` → `User` file would look like this, of course:

```json
[
    { "keys": ["f12"], "command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": false}}
]
```

Comment: I think reindent should have a default key binding. In emacs you use the TAB key (no modifier) for this. I propose the alt+tab key binding as the tab key is already related to indentation commands.

Comment: alt+tab? that's used for switching windows!

Comment: Oops! It shows that I am on a Mac. Maybe the windows_key + tab?

Comment: no problem, in fact all those keys are already used: win+tab selects a window from the taskbar, ctrl+tab switches tabs, shift+tab unindents

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The short cut doesn't get set (in the menu it doesn't update the shortcut), nor does it work.

Comment: @NunoGonçalves the menu does not show the new shortcut but it should work. make sure your Preferences - Keybindings-User contains exactly those lines and **save that file**. Also make sure ST knows which kind of filetype/syntax it should use (is your syntax highlighting correct?). If it still does not work try a different key (e.g. "f8" seems unused) then if that does not work either check whether user defined keybindings are disabled on your installation for some reason.

Comment: Having done nothing, it suddenly started working. :) I guess the problem was between the keyboard and the chair all along :) Thank you anyway. :)

Comment: Mac users do use "super+h" or other binding that is not taken ... super = command button

Comment: @gdelfino please don't bother proposing any shortcut again.. Win+tab is also used for switching between windows *win 7 user

Comment: { "keys": ["f12"], "command": "reindent", "args": { "single_line": false } } will reindent all document without need to select what you want

Comment: And how to do that on a folder?

Comment: `"f12"` is used for `"goto_definition"` in Sublime Text 3. I would recommend `"ctrl+\\"`, as it is right next to the indent `[` `]` keys. The extra "\" is for escaping.

Comment: I can't understand why they don't make the indentation associated to a specific shortcut by default!! This is a very basic thing !!!!

Comment: Windows: `{"keys": ["alt+shift+r"], "command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": false}}` Mac: `{ "keys": ["command+shift+r"], "command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": false} }  `

Answer (score 279):

The reindent command only works on the currently selected lines unless the "single_line" argument is set to false.

```
{ "keys": ["f12"], "command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": false} }
```

Now, pressing <kbd>f12</kbd> will reindent the entire document.

Comment: "current line" can be a selection with multiple lines in it.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer (or at least merged into the accepted one), since in Visual Studio Ctrl+K+D will also reformat the entire document.

Comment: swap out ["f12"] for ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+d"] for the two-press chord.

Comment: [
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+f"], "command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": false} } 
]
This is my customize, thanks so much!!!

Comment: If you select all the lines and run the shortcut then formatting will work entire file:)

Comment: Thank you for the "plus" ( "args": {"single_line": false} ) very usefull !

Answer (score 33):

No one seems to love mac re-indentation, So here How I do it:

```
[
   { "keys": ["command+shift+i"], "command": "reindent"}
]
```

In Preferences > Key Binding - User

One more extra tip: 
add

```
{ "keys": ["command+0"], "command": "focus_side_bar" }
```

to have sidebar file tree view navigation using keyboard.

Note: 
Add , at the end of each {}, if you have more than one {} set of objects

Comment: please don't use Comma (,) at the end of the statement. It gave me an error. Type it without the comma (,)

Comment: if you're not a Mac user use ctrl instead of command    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+i"], "command": "reindent"}

Answer (score 30):

There is no default shortcut for reindenting a file.  However you can create one by following [eznme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9497589/645491)'s answer above.

You can also use the [Command Palette](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/command_palette.html) by pressing:

1. <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+Shift+<kbd>P</kbd> on a Mac)
2. Type the first few characters of **Reindent** e.g: `rein`
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run the command
   (The first command at the top should now show **Indentation: Reindent Lines**)

Answer (score 19):

For those interested it is easy to change but for a lover of Netbeans and the auto-format you can change the key binding from <kbd>F12</kbd> to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to use your beloved key binding. Sad part is that you have to select all to format the entire file. Netbeans still has the upper hand on that. If anyone knows how to overcome that limitation I'm all ears. Otherwise happy reindenting (auto-formating).

Comment: Not sure if anyone still looking at this but to respond to @jeff. Use , "args": {"single_line": false} after adding the command and then you dont need to select lines to format it. It format the entire document for you. (Nick has put in the fool command)

Comment: NetBeans shortcut is Alt+Shift+F (by default; Ctrl+Shift+F opens Project Search), and is limited and not necessarily sensible (CSS doesn't work, and it may keep new code lines on the same line). Eclipse's shortcut is Ctrl+Shift+F, and it's better in some ways, and works on CSS, but still has an issue with new code lines. Both of them have some issues with new lines for inner-line attributes (like in HTML), though you can configure somewhat (more in Eclipse).

Comment: cmd+a on mac or ctrl+a on windows will automatically select all the text for you in the current window. so do that, and then whatever key binding you chose for auto indenting to reformat the whole file.

Answer (score 17):

To indent with the same keys like Visual Studio <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (I am a Visual Studio user so I am used to this combination) I suggest:

```
[
{ "keys": ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+d"], "command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": false} }
]
```

Write this on Preferences>Key Bindings - User

Answer (score 7):

It is very simple. Just go to `Edit=>Line=>Reindent`

Answer (score 7):

#### Netbeans like Shortcut Key

Go to `Preferences` > `Key Bindings` > `User` and **add** the code below:

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+f"], "command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": false} }
]
```

**Usage**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Answer (score 6):

Select all code that you intend to indent, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> in Sublime text to indent.

For macOS users, use <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> to indent, and <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> to un-indent.

Answer (score 4):

### [code formatter](https://github.com/akalongman/sublimetext-codeformatter).

simple to use.

---

1.Install

---

2.press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> (default)

---

Thats it.

Comment: doesn't work for me, it just disables indentation across all lines.

Comment: I am using it since quite some time.Its woking fine .whats the problem. Was the installation succesful.

Comment: Of course yes, I am using it against HTML snippets... all the lines got their indents removed. Looking like a poem... :(

Answer (score 2):

Beside of the inbuilt 'reindent' function, you can also install other plugins, such as [SublimeAStyleFormatter](http://theo.im/SublimeAStyleFormatter/) and [CodeFormatter](https://github.com/akalongman/sublimetext-codeformatter). These plugins are better for their specify language.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case this stop working for anyone like me, in OS X, the command key is identified as `super`so it should be able to do something like this:

```
[
    {
    "keys": ["super+i"], 
    "command": "reindent", 
    "args": {
        "single_line": 
        false}
    } 
]
```

in this case using <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> is going to indent your whole code (eclipse like :) )

Answer (score 1):

I used to use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> in NetBeans, I checked and there isn't any collision in the default keymap array of sublime, so I added it to my sublime and I'm using it without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

For those who like the default key binding for **IntelJ IDEA**, select **Preferences** > **Settings - User**:

[image]

And paste in the following to have the <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd> shortcut for auto indent:

```
[
   { "keys": ["command+shift+l"], "command": "reindent"}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a shortcut by going to the menu **Preferences** → **Keybindings** → **User**, then add there:

```
{ "keys": ["f12"], "command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": false} }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Auto-Formatting in Sublime Text 2: Install Package: Tag from Command Palette, then go to Edit -> Tag -> Auto-Format Tags on Document

Answer (score 0):

This is my configuration for sublime-keymap:

```
[
  {
    "keys": [",+=+="],
    "command": "reindent",
    "args": {
      "single_line": false
    }
  }
]
```

For **vim** people, just use `,==` to reindent the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Open Sublime Text.
2. Open **Preferences**.
3. Open **Key Bindings -User**.
4. Put below code:

```
[{"keys": ["ctrl+shift+c"], "command": "reindent"},]
```

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and you also use other key shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Select everything, or whatever you want to re-indent and do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. 
This is really quick and painless.

Answer (score 0):

```
{ "keys": ["f12"], "command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": false} }
```

You can get the reindent option by using the above code