# How to insert spaces in front of selected lines?

Tags: sublimetext2

Is there any way to add space or tab(4 spaces) in front of several selected lines?
Because now if change the code I hava to press command + click select each line.

Thanks.

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495007/indenting-code-in-sublime-text-2

Comment: The answer does tab(4 spaces), but is there also a way to do individual spaces?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried

```
CTRL + ]
CTRL + [
```

(square brackets).

Or use

```
Edit -> Line -> Reindent
```

Comment: This does tab(4 spaces), but is there also a way to do individual spaces?

Comment: @tscizzle I added an answer to insert individual spaces. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 9):

To insert *individual* spaces, click on the beginning of the line, then use cmd (for Mac) or ctrl (for Windows) and click on the beginning of other lines. It's the same way as how you select multiple files at once. Now when you add a space in front, it will add to all the lines that you selected.

Comment: Ya, that's actually how I do it now, but I want one where you "highlight" the lines instead of Cmd-click, because dragging the cursor to make a selection include lines is suuuper easy.

Comment: Or on a mac click the first line you want to move, hold option, drag straight down and this will select multiple lines. Then just add tabs or spaces at will. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

First set your TAB(4 spaces) width by selecting

```
View > Indentation > Tab Width: 4
```

then select the number of lines(text blocks) that you wanna shift towards **RIGHT**.

Finally Hit(**On MAC**)

```
Command + Tab    OR
Command + [
```

and Hit (**On Windows**)

```
Ctrl + Tab       OR
Ctrl + [
```

Answer (score 0):

#### To use indentation with 2 SPACES

```
View > Indentation > Indent Using Spaces

View > Indentation > Tab Width: 2
```