# HAML text formatting in SublimeText2

Tags: haml, sublimetext2

"Edit, Line, Reindent" doesn't work for HAML. Is there a command that will auto-format HAML? Any ideas? thanks

Comment: Does this post answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495007/indenting-code-in-sublime-text-2

Answer (score 1):

Automatically re-indenting HAML is not possible, because the amount of spaces in front determines where the element is nested or should come after the previous element.

Consider the following case:

```
.table
      .row
```

When you re-indent it might to

```
.table
.row
```

while want you want is

```
.table
  .row
```

In the above example I used meaningful names and we might be able to understand that `row` is a child of `table` but the editor does not.

Even if we did somehow did teach the editor that rows are always part of a table, it doesn't mean that is always the case.

The following example shows you why

```
.table
  .row
     .table
        .row
                  .row Which table has two rows?
```

Afterall both

```
.table
  .row
    .table
      .row
      .row
```

and

```
.table
  .row
    .table
      .row
  .row
```

are valid solutions. The first option has the inner table have two rows, while the second option is that outer table has two rows.

**tl;dr-version:** There is no auto-indent function for HAML in Sublime Text and there will most likely never be one as it is *almost* impossible to determine what the HAML-author means.