# Python expected an indented block on sublime text 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, sublimetext3

This is an example excerpt from a bigger code, I have no idea why is this not properly idented

Code example :

```
if True:
    for i in range(1, 10):
        print(i)
    print("Inside the if")
    print("But outside the loop")
```

Actual code :

```
def mkfolder(self):
    path = self.edit_dir.text()
    prefix,fromn,ton,formatn
    if not os.path.isdir(path):
        return self.showerror("Erro de parâmetro", "Caminho para criar as pastas é inválido ou não existe\nCód.: 0052")
    if not self.chk_prefix.isChecked():
        prefix = ""
    else:
        prefix = self.edit_prefix.text()    
    if self.chk_count.isChecked():
        fromn = self.spin_from.getValue()
        ton = self.spin_to.getValue()
        formatn = self.spin_format.getValue()
        if ton <= fromn:
            return self.showerror("Erro de parâmetro", "Não é possível fazer uma contagem regressiva\nCód.: 0010")
        if len(str(abs(ton))) < formatn:
            return self.showerror("Erro de parâmetro", "Quantidade de dígitos é insuficiente\nCód.: 0012")
        strFormat = "{0:0>"+ str(formatn) +"}"
        msg = self.askquestion("Aviso", str(ton - fromn) + " pastas\n Em " + path + "\n De '" + prefix + strFormat.format(fromn) + "'\na '"+ pref+ strFormat.format(ton) +"'\n\nConfirma?")
        if msg==22:

            for i in range(fromn, ton+1):
                os.makedirs(path + "/"+ prefix + strFormat.format(i))           
            self.tomain()
            self.mkclean()
```

Comment: You've mixed tabs and spaces. Why `if True`, though?

Comment: IntelliJ has a quick option that automatically converts between tabs/spaces, and even line endings iirc.

Comment: @Carcigenicate so does Sublime.

Answer (score 0):

It is improperly indented because you're mixing tabs and spaces. Don't do that. Python doesn't like it when you do that. Every time you do that, a puppy cries

Comment: It seems that my code is full of those after I switched IDEs, any quick solution?

Comment: @Mojimi SublimeText3 should be able to handle that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22529265/sublime-text-3-convert-spaces-to-tabs

Comment: `find-replace`. Find a tab (`'\t'`), replace with four spaces. Alternatively, run this on the commandline: `python -c 'import sys; with open(sys.argv[-1]) as infile: contents = infile.read().replace('\t', '    '); with open(sys.argv[-1], 'w') as outfile: outfile.write(contents) path/to/file`

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, you've got inconsistent tabs and spaces. Some text editors have special "Tab Characters" that add the spacing, while others simply convert a tab into multiple "Space Characters". I would recommend looking into how to show non-printing characters in your text editor to see which lines are spaced and which are tabbed.

Answer (score 0):

Might be this tool come in handy to check Indentation in Python

https://pythoniter.appspot.com/

Additional: Make your code look professional

http://pep8online.com/