# How to change tab size in all files after changing the sublime text settings

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm using tabulations in all my files and I want to keep using them. But I've been working with the default setting:

`"tab_size": 4`

Until now. I just changed the size to `2` in the User Preferences file. When I create a new file, it's correctly using the size of 2 spaces when I tab. But I can't find how to quickly modify all my already existing files.

I'd like to do a simple "Search & Replace" but I would have `\t` in both fields, which is sadly not working.

I tried changing the `View -> Indentation -> Tab Width: 4` to `Tab Width: 2`, it seems to change the way I see the file (I see tabs with size of 2 spaces instead of 4) but it's just the view and it's not modifying the file.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about sublime text 3 but I would suggest you convert tabs to spaces, then do a search an replace 4->2 and then reconvert spaces to tabs.

It would seem that option is also under View -> Indentation

Possibly useful link : 
[Sublime Text 3, convert spaces to tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22529265/sublime-text-3-convert-spaces-to-tabs)