# TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation when building code with Sublime text 3

Tags: python, sublimetext3, indentation

So i decided that i switch to sublime text 3 because IDLE doesn't have the autocomplete feature and it makes my development process slow. But when i try to build my code this is what happens. Did not face the same with IDLE. AM i missing something ?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22529265/sublime-text-3-convert-spaces-to-tabs

Comment: In Python the very widely-accepted practice is to indent with 4 spaces. Please see the duplicate question for how to set that permanently.