# Improper sublime indentation for PHP files

Tags: php, editor, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, indentation

I have been using a custom shortcut to indent in Sublime Text referred in this post [Indent multiple lines in Sublime Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495007/indenting-code-in-sublime-text-2)

But it doesn't work if there are an odd number of spaces. Like my tab size is set to 2 spaces, and when there are 3 spaces at the beginning of any line it doesn't indent the remaining code.

for example:

```php
<?php

function test_indent() {
  if (condition) {
   echo "here";
  }
   else {
    echo "else";
   }
}
```

And when I indent with the custom shortcut specified in the above post, which is:

```json
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+f"], "command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": false} }
```

for me, it results like:

```php
function test_indent() {
  if (condition) {
   echo "here";
 }
 else {
  echo "else";
}
}
```

What do I need to do to make it indent properly?

Comment: while playing around with this, I discovered that if you completely `unindent` your file first, `reindent` will work as expected

Comment: I am totally agree with you. but there should be a better solution for this.

Comment: This behaviour seems to affect many types of files - not just PHP

Comment: I have raised an issue https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/2027

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While playing around with this, I discovered that if you completely `unindent` the selection first, then `reindent` will work as expected. It seems like it is a bug in the `reindent` command that occurs when the indentation isn't a multiple of the "tab size" that is set.

Therefore, we can workaround this bug by changing your shortcut to completely unindent the selection and then re-indent it again.

From the `Tools` menu, select `Developer` -> `New Plugin...`

Select everything and replace it with the following:

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin
import re

class UnindentAndReindentCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        while any([sel for sel in self.view.sel() if re.search('^[ \t]+', self.view.substr(sel.cover(self.view.line(sel.begin()))), re.MULTILINE)]):
            self.view.run_command('unindent')
        self.view.run_command('reindent', { 'single_line': False })
```

Save it, in the location that ST suggests, as something like `fix_reindent.py` - file extension is important but the base name isn't.

Then, change your keybinding to use the new `unindent_and_reindent` command we just created:

```json
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+f"], "command": "unindent_and_reindent" }
```

And it will now correctly reindent your code.